# Justified paragraph followed by right-aligned paragraph with custom spacing

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment, paragraphs

I'd like to have a paragraph of ordinary text with a single right-aligned line underneath, with a custom vertical spacing (0.5 cm) between them, but can't figure out how it is done. My best guess is:

```
A paragraph of ordinarily justified text blah blah blah followed
by a line which has a different alignment. \\[0.5cm] {\raggedleft 
the right aligned text}
```

This doesn't work. The vertical spacing is fine, but "the right aligned text" is aligned to the left.

If I change it to

```
A paragraph of ordinarily justified text blah blah blah followed
by a line which has a different alignment. \\[0.5cm] 

{\raggedleft the right aligned text}
```

then the alignment works fine, but the vertical spacing is much greater than 0.5 cm. Help?

Comment: you should be able to get the right-alignment by just adding `\par` before the final brace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand:

```
\documentclass{article} 

\begin{document}

\newlength{\myskip}
\setlength{\myskip}{0.5cm}
\addtolength{\myskip}{-\baselineskip}
A paragraph of ordinarily justified text blah blah blah followed
by a line which has a different alignment.  And some more and more text.
\vskip\myskip

\rightline{the right aligned text}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I am assuming, that 5 mm is the distance between baselines, hence the correction. If no, you can put the vertical skip without such manipulations.

Answer (score 2):

Presumably one should worry about page breaking between the paragraph and the right-aligned text. Here's a non-breaking version:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\begin{document}

A paragraph of ordinarily justified text blah blah blah followed
by a line which has a different alignment.\rule[-.5cm]{0cm}{.5cm}\\*
\null\hfill the right aligned text.

\end{document}
```

The `\rule[-.5cm]{0cm}{.5cm}` creates a strut: a zero width rule that extends .5cm below the baseline.